# Почему с конца 30-х перестали употреблять словосочетание "в Украине"?

Tags: история-языка, предлоги

В русском языке сочетание "в Украине" используется издавна.

> Господин гетман, <...> того ради вам надлежит итти по Киева, в Украйну свою и смотреть того, о чем уже вы известны. 
>   *(К Мазепе)*
>
> А ныне по всем обстоятелствам идет в Украйну [чево болше не чаю для лесов]. *(К Б. Шереметьеву)*
>
> *Из писем императора Петра Великого, июль-декабрь 1708 г.*
>
> Итак, я еду в Украйну, а Вы, крокодил, остаетесь в тундре.  *(Из письма А. П. Чехова И. Леонтьеву)*
>
> Багратион долго не присоединяется (хотя в этом главная цель всех начальствующих лиц) потому, что ему кажется, что он на этом марше ставит в опасность свою армию и что выгоднее всего для него отступить левее и южнее, беспокоя с фланга и тыла неприятеля и комплектуя свою армию в Украине. *(Л.Н.Толстой."Война и мир")*

В текстах 18-19 века из Корпуса русского языка, сочетания "в Украине" и "на Украине" встречаются примерно одинаково часто (20 и 28 раз), и без всякой связи с политикой.

"В Украине" продолжало употребляться и после революции, например:

> Дошкольные учреждения охватывают детей с 3 ― 8-летнего возраста, и установленный в Украине законом прием детей в дошкольные учреждения с 4-летнего возраста обусловливается не принципиальным расхождением с РСФСР, а соображениями практического порядка.    *(Резолюция совещания наркомов просвещения СССР о системах народного просвещения. (1920-1925)*
>
> ...участники «право-троцкистского блока» подготовляли повстанческие банды в Сибири, на Северном Кавказе, в Украине, Белоруссии, Узбекистане и других местностях Советского Союза. *(Из приговора Военной Коллегии Верховного Суда СССР по делу «право-троцкистского блока», 1938)*

Но после 1938 года употребление "в Украине" прекращается до 2000 года ([ссылка](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=30552&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexform&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%20%F3%EA%F0%E0%E8%ED%E5&p=3)), за единственным исключением "Памятных записок" Кагановича (1961-1991).

Как и почему словосочетание "в Украине" вдруг исчезло?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы привести какие-то конкретные доказательства утверждения "Но после 1938 года употребление "в Украине" прекращается до 2000 года..."

иначе очень похоже на то, что вопрос - кандидат в удалённые.

Comment: @shabunc - http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=30552&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexform&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%20%F3%EA%F0%E0%E8%ED%E5&p=3

Comment: @shabunc - перед "иначе" в вашем комменте нужна запятая.

Comment: Корпус не очень представителен для 18 и 19 века. Тексты до 1900 года составляют лишь 21% корпуса. Строго говоря, стоит собирать сочетания *в Украину(-е)* и *на Украину(-е)*. Тогда обнаружится, что "в" используется в 98 случаях, а "на" — в  84 случаях. И тут есть один звоночек: 68 из 98 употреблений содержатся в текстах двух авторов, где много упоминаний об Украине. Лишний повод усомниться в том, что по этим данным можно сказать что-то кроме того, что, по-видимому, сочетания по частоте отличались явно не в 10 раз.

Comment: Я бы предположил, что связано это было с тем, что именно в начале XX века, в 20-30-х голах скрупулёзно кодифицировался "стандартный русский язык". Сейчас действующие нормы правописания — 1956 года, если я правильно помню. Понятно, что начиная с этого момента "правильным" преимущественно признавался только один вариант. Для "Украины" по традиции, судя по всему, был выбран вариант "на Украину/Украине" (если отбросить очевидную неравномерность в корпусе, то он, похоже, и правда был популярнее)

Comment: Похоже, Майдан и досюда добрался

Comment: В Украине? Тогда "в Урале", "в Урал"? Или "в окраине", "в окраину"?

Comment: @BrainsFeeder - "во сибирской во украине, во Даурской стороне..." (народная песня 17 века).

Comment: - Батько, сколько раз надо тебе повторить? Не "На Украине" а "В Украине!" - Сынко, не пийшов бы ту в х--?

Answer (score 6):

С начала 20-го века, по тем же данным из корпуса, предлог "в" почти не используется. Пик соотношения частот употребления "в Украине"/"на Украине" в первой половине 20 века приходится на 1934 год и составляет приблизительно 5%, причем частично "в" используется с названием гостиницы "Украина", как видно из текстов, поэтому реальное соотношение еще ниже.

Можно предположить, что частично это связано с советской украинизацией 20-х ― 30-х гг., подробно освещенной в книге Борисенок "Феномен советской украинизации". Этот процесс закончился как раз в середине 30-х (и началась борьба с буржуазным национализмом). Но это только предположение. Аргументы в пользу "в" ― альтернативная этимология (не от "окраины") и независимая территория. Я не знаю, когда появилась альтернатавная этимология, но подозреваю, что позднее. А вот относительно независимая республика (по сравнению с дореволюционным статусом) ― это подчеркивалось, возможно, и таким образом. Это, конечно, касается только советской литературы и прессы.

Пара примеров в корпусе ― из Краснова и Трубецкого, которые вряд ли оглядывались на советское употребление.

Была ли какая-то директива в 30-х годах по поводу употребления предлога, мне неизвестно. Но примеров настолько мало (а еще меньше "в Украину", "на Украину") что статистическая значимость именно 38-го года вообще сомнительна.

[image: Частота на миллион словоформ, Национальный корпус русского языка]

[график на сайте корпуса](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D0%B2%C2%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5&t2=%D0%BD%D0%B0%C2%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5&start=1800&end=2013&smoothing=3)

Comment: подборка цветов в кассу )))

Answer (score 4):

Если проложить аналогию с предлогами с/со, к/ко, употребление которых определяется удобством произношения, то и предлоги в/на по отношению к Украине могут сменять друг друга по той же причине. Если произносить "Украина" с коротким "У", то предлог удобнее с гласной буквой, и наоборот. Возможно, это связано с [изменяющейся постановкой ударения](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&ag=x&word=%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0). Так как предлоги синонимичны, то их употребление постепенно меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Украина происходит от "окраина". В русском языке говорят: на окраину, на окраине. Например: жить на окраине села, переехать на окраину города и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос звучит так: "почему перестали употреблять". Раньше употребляли, а теперь - не употребляют. Почему-то перестали. Почему? Этимология слова за это время не могла ведь измениться, значит причина не в этимологии?

Comment: @Artemix: regardless of the correctness of this very answer, there is such thing as folk etymology: how the speakers perceive the origin or the word. If grammar or syntax is governed by etymology, folk etymology can replace the original. Compare the fleeting vowel in *брелки* (which had been borrowed long since the fall of the reduced) or English "shit/shat" which is rethought as a class 5 strong verb by analogy with "sit".

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes, if we are talking about folk etymology then the origins of the word can be rethinked in 5 years (thanks to Zadornov for instance).

Comment: «Краснодарский край» происходит от слова «край», но при этом никто не говорит «на Краснодарском краю». Многозначные слова могут приобретать разные парадигмы для разных значений. Вопрос задан конкретный - когда и почему употребление «на Украине» стало нормой, а не о том откуда оно в принципе возникло и чем оно лучше других вариантов.

Comment: Artemix "Этимология слова за это время не могла ведь измениться, значит причина не в этимологии" - вообще не понимаю эту фразу, а вы сами понимаете ? :>

Comment: " но при этом никто не говорит «на Краснодарском краю»." - можно и так сказать :> Если шире и неопределеннее

Answer (score -5):

For 20th and 21st century the "на" preposition is for territories, the "в" - for independent countries. Your information means that since 1938 it was not understood as an independent country (and it could be understood so in the early USSR according to the USSR 1st Constitution). For Tchekhov it would not mean that yet probably, but then it became so. Simiar situation is with Cuba - if you say "посол на Кубе", not "посол в Кубе", you insult Cuba's independence, and some people may attack you for that (whereas others don't care).

Comment: "For 20th and 21st century the "на" preposition is for territories, the "в" - for independent countries."  Почему же тогда не говорили "на Белоруссии", "на Армении", "на Сибири" и т.д.?

Comment: Not that again! Although the example with insulted Cubans is something new.

Comment: I guess those Ukrainians are insulted by a rather close resemblance to the окраина.

Comment: @BrainsFeeder And why is that, I wonder? :). Certainly, such resemblance is pure coincidence, yeah. To be fair, there are other traditional uses with "на", for example, *"на Руси"* (and yet, *"в Древней Руси"*). Sometimes language combines rules with set phrases that are said like that just because that's how people speak.

Comment: "посол в Кубе" - it's from mathematics ))

Comment: @Shady_arc I would say that most toponyms on -ина follow the same pattern (_на Псковщине, на Полтавщине_). Also _на Волыни, на равнине, на родине_. On the other hand, _в 
Сербской Краине_. I mean the correlation between "на" and just "окраина" seems overrated.

Comment: @J-mster and mostly words with -ina are not independent countries, are they?

Comment: Куба - это остров (и так стереотипно воспринимается прежде всего; это не только к ней относится); поэтому всегда будет "на"

Comment: For the Chekhov, this definitely could not be mean as an "independent country" in any case  :)
And not for anyone in the Russian Empire.
Rather, it is simplistic as a village or a city, probably, or  governorate and "INTO this" :>