# "На Украине" or "В Украине"?

Tags: предлоги

This question has already been asked [here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/why-do-some-say-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-and-others-%D0%B2-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-and-what-is-correct), but it lacks some authoritative sources there. I once stumbled upon a source saying that in case with a territory it is correct to say "на" ("на Руси", "на Кубани", "на Урале"), and in case with a separate state, it is correct to say "в" ("в Японии", "в Ираке", "в России", "в Италии") with some exceptions of some island states when saying "на" can also be okay ("на Кипре", "на Ямайке", "на Мальте"). I can't find that source now, but I suspect that it was written long before this war in Ukraine, and even long before Ukraine became a separate state. And it looks like saying "на Украине", though quite against the above-mentioned rule, still seems to be okay - as a kind of exception to the rule.

Can anyone cite an authoritative source specifically addressing this case of "на Украине vs. в Украине"?

Comment: This question already has some answers. If you think the question itself needs proof of notability (which I personally doubt), please add them to the original question.

Comment: You can try reading http://lurkmore.to/%D0%92/%D0%BD%D0%B0 this. It is not an authoritative source, but it covers the question pretty well, if you can make it through tons of slang. And there are some links to authoritative sources.

Comment: @Quassnoi Не думаю что это дубликат. В вопросе есть ссылка на тот же вопрос, который стоит в причине закрытия и объяснено почему ответы оттуда не вполне подходят.

Comment: @Alissa: *This question has already been asked here, but it lacks some authoritative sources there*. Source to what, questions, or answers? I don't see how adding the sources to the question would make it any different. If the op is looking for answers with the sources, they could edit the original question, specifically asking for sources.

Comment: @Alissa: and frankly speaking, I don't think we need more than one instance of this particular question on this site.